# After an image has been uploaded into database, the webpage does not load properly unless refreshed

Tags: php, html, css

I recently altered some code of mine into a prepared statement to a form which essentially allows a user to simply upload an image and save in the database. Ever since I made some changes to the SQL query, after the upload button is pressed, only half of the webpage reloads again.

Webpage before an image is uploaded:
[image: Webpage before an image is uploaded]

Then this is the webpage after an image is uploaded, the rest of the screen just dissapears:
[image: Webpage after an image is uploaded]

I checked MAMPS apache error log and this is the last log that's on there
`[Mon Mar 11 20:35:04 2019] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhotoClub/style.css, referer: http://localhost:8888/PhotoClub/after-login.php?login=success`

Which doesn't make any sense to me with it to do with the CSS file as the link to this is at the top of the page:

```
    <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Dashboard</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="blog, tech, girl, techblog, gallery, coder, techblog, trends, fashion, beauty"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="CSS/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

The weird thing is that in the error log it doesn't seem to say the correct file path name even which is: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhotoClub/CSS/style.css` It's almost like it's missing out the CSS from the file path?

The html code for the form:

```
<div class="grid-2">
                    <p><b>Upload photo entries here!</b></p>
                    <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <label>Select Competition</label>
                        <select name="catID">
                          <option value="">Default</option>
                          <option value="1">Winter Warmer</option>
                          <option value="2">Fresh New Year</option>
                          <option value="3">Month of Love</option>
                          <option value="4">Seaside Scenery</option>
                        </select>
                    </fieldset>

                    <label>Enter Member ID</label>
                        <input type ="text" name ="member-id" placeholder="Enter Your Member ID...">
                        <label>Enter Title</label> 
                        <input type ="text" name ="img-title" placeholder="Enter Title...">
                      <table width="300" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="box">
                        <tr> 
                          <td width="246">
                            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000"> <!-- 2 Megabytes -->
                            <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile"> 
                          </td>
                          <td width="80">
                            <input name="upload" type="submit" id="upload" value="Upload "> <!-- A button -->
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </form>
```

The php code:

```
<?php
                        $uploadDir = 'images/';


                        if(isset($_POST['upload']))
                        {
                          $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                          $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
                          $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
                          $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
                          $memberID = $_POST['member-id'];
                          $imgTitle = $_POST['img-title'];
                          $catID = $_POST['catID'];

                          $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;

                          $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);

                          if (!$result) {
                            echo "Error uploading file";
                    exit;
                  }
                else{
                  echo "<br>Files uploaded<br>";
                }

                if(mysqli_connect_errno())
                {
                  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                    exit();
                }

                if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                {
                $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
                $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
                } 


                $stmt = $conn->prepare ("INSERT INTO tblImage (fldImageID, fldMemberID, fldCatID, fldFilePath, fldName) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

                $stmt->bind_param("iiss", $memberID, $catID, $filePath, $imgTitle); 
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt) or die ("");

                //2. $query = "SELECT `fldImageID` FROM `tblImage` ORDER BY `fldImageID` DESC LIMIT 1";
                //3. Then I need a query to update the membEntComp or comp Table
                }

                  ?>
```

Comment: Does the image actually get uploaded? Seems like your page stops rendering at `if(mysqli_connect_errno())`. Also, check your dev tools console for errors.

Comment: Image gets uploaded to the correct table as should, and no errors in the console at all. It's baffling me!

Comment: Hi @ArtisticPhoenix Just had a quick look at your link, where do I place the URL you refer to in my code ?

Comment: Like @j08691 said, it looks like your script is exiting somewhere. `$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt) or die ("");` -- if you replace that empty string with some text, do you see it on screen? **Edit**: I'm pretty sure this is where the problem is. `mysqli_stmt_get_result` returns `false` for INSERT queries.

Comment: Hi @ArtisticPhoenix I don't have any background images per say, It's just once the user browses for an image on their PC, then clicks upload the rest of my html/css completely disappears apart from that form html strangely.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I just placed some text in where you suggested and when I uploaded another image, that text I added in appeared on screen and the rest of the page still disappeared. Do you know why it's exiting, yet still placing the image into my table

Comment: The INSERT query is working correctly, but since `mysqli_stmt_get_result()` returns `false` your `or die()` code is fired. You can only use that function with a SELECT query.

Comment: I am getting all in a tangle with this upload an image code to the database. Its tricky as we were given this code via University and then I tried to ensure that the code was then protected from SQL injection, so I've messed up somewhere. Which lines should I delete/get rid of do you guys/girls think?

Comment: That 2.) and 3.) are commented out, thats a reminder to me. Sorry please ignore those

Comment: @rickdenhaan - ok I see it now, I can't stand badly formatted code, messes with my dyslexia ... lol ... to many comments so I removed them as they are not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare ("INSERT INTO tblImage (fldImageID, fldMemberID, fldCatID, fldFilePath, fldName) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param("iiss", $memberID, $catID, $filePath, $imgTitle); 
$stmt->execute();
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt) or die ("");
```

You cannot use `mysqli_stmt_get_result()` on an `INSERT` query, as [it only works for `SELECT` queries](http://secure.php.net/mysqli_stmt_get_result#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.get-result-returnvalues).

Since it returns `false`, your `or die("")` code is fired and your script stops executing there.

Instead, you can check the return value for `$stmt->execute()` to see if the query was executed successfully. To avoid confusion the next time, I'd add a more useful error message within the `die("")`:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare ("INSERT INTO tblImage (fldImageID, fldMemberID, fldCatID, fldFilePath, fldName) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param("iiss", $memberID, $catID, $filePath, $imgTitle); 
$stmt->execute() or die("Failed to insert image into the database");
```

Or, more transparent (but essentially the same thing):

```
$result = $stmt->execute();

if (!$result) {
    die("Failed to insert image into the database");
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much @rickdenhaan This really did stress me out, I'm still new to this all so the way you've explained it to me, I really understand so thank you for your help! and ignore my badly indented code haha :-)

Comment: Real Quick.... does this mean I can get rid of the code above starting from    `if (!$result) {
                            echo "Error uploading file";`

Comment: No, that checks a different step of the process. You should keep that.